# magento 1.9 | process starts mysql on its own

Tags: magento-1.9, database

My site automatically turns on mysql process, which loads the database and CPU  sometimes to  120% and some other processes are also running, but I can’t understand what it. because of this, the site slows down

I tried to kill processes, but they start again, how can I be with this. help me please

[image]

Comment: Something cron related maybe. check which query takes much time.

Comment: I watched no crowns running, and when killed cron process,if you kill the cron, he will wait for the next launch, and not start immediately

Comment: Have you considered turning on your General Log for 5-minutes to observe the queries that are running from 'nowhere'?  Remember to turn OFF the General Log to avoid filling your storage device.  Is this a vendor-supplied package?  If so contact them.